# Tengo problemas con left join de 3 tablas

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E hice esto

```
select    dp.nombre as 'Nombre Departamento', ag.nombre as 'Nombre Asignatura'
FROM (((asignatura ag
left JOIN alumno_se_matricula_asignatura asma  ON asma.id_asignatura=ag.id)
left JOIN profesor pf  ON pf.id_profesor=ag.id_profesor)
left join departamento dp on pf.id_departamento = dp.id)
where asma.id_curso_escolar is null
order by ag.nombre;
```

Pero creo que no está bien, empecé un curso en el trabajo y lo del left join me ha complicado muchísimo.

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar

Comment: A que te refieres que no esta bien? Te sale un error? No te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes y tratando de entender el problema.

- Primero necesitamos "todos los departamentos". Eso nos indica que `Departamento` debe ser nuestra tabla principal.
- Después seguimos con "que tengan una asignatura". Eso indica que siempre habrá una asignatura que corresponda al departamento y viceversa. Para lograr eso, necesitamos la tabla `asignatura`, pero también necesitamos la tabla intermedia `profesor` para poder relacionar las asignaturas con los departamentos.
- Finalmente, tenemos "que no se haya impartido en ningún curso escolar". Aquí y solo aquí es cuando necesitamos usar el LEFT JOIN, porque nos permite ver las asignaturas que no están relacionadas con los cursos.

Traducido a SQL, queda más o menos así:

```
SELECT dp.nombre as 'Nombre Departamento', 
       ag.nombre as 'Nombre Asignatura'
FROM       departamento                     d --Obtenemos todos los departamentos
INNER JOIN profesor                         p    ON d.id = p.id_departamento  --Unimos a los departamentos con las asignaturas por medio de profesores
INNER JOIN asignatura                       a    ON p.id = a.id_profesor  -- Obtenemos las asignaturas de los departamentos
LEFT  JOIN alumno_se_matricula_asignatura   asma ON a.id = asma.id_asignatura -- Obtenemos la relación entre asignaturas y cursos
WHERE  asma.id_curso_escolar IS NULL -- Esto indica que no hay un curso relacionado
```

Ahora, para este tipo de problemas, hay otras alternativas que llegan a ser más eficientes y/o más claras. Esto es mediante el uso de `NOT IN()` o `NOT EXISTS()`

Ejemplos:

```
SELECT dp.nombre as 'Nombre Departamento', 
       ag.nombre as 'Nombre Asignatura'
FROM       departamento                     d --Obtenemos todos los departamentos
INNER JOIN profesor                         p    ON d.id = p.id_departamento  --Unimos a los departamentos con las asignaturas por medio de profesores
INNER JOIN asignatura                       a    ON p.id = a.id_profesor  -- Obtenemos las asignaturas de los departamentos
WHERE a.id NOT IN(SELECT asma.id_asignatura FROM alumno_se_matricula_asignatura asma) -- Decimos que la asignatura no esté en las asignaturas guardadas en la tabla alumno_se_matricula_asignatura


SELECT dp.nombre as 'Nombre Departamento', 
       ag.nombre as 'Nombre Asignatura'
FROM       departamento                     d --Obtenemos todos los departamentos
INNER JOIN profesor                         p    ON d.id = p.id_departamento  --Unimos a los departamentos con las asignaturas por medio de profesores
INNER JOIN asignatura                       a    ON p.id = a.id_profesor  -- Obtenemos las asignaturas de los departamentos
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                FROM alumno_se_matricula_asignatura asma
                WHERE a.id = asma.id_asignatura) -- Decimos que no existauna fila en la tabla alumno_se_matricula_asignatura que se relacione con las asignaturas previas
```

Como nota importante, debes recordar que la función `NOT IN()` no regresará resultados si la columna de la subconsulta tiene un nulo. Además `EXISTS()` permite comparar múltiples columnas.